# Build a .so file from multiple C++ files and use it

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

I have a tree of programs that contains

`outter.cc, outter.h`
`b.cc, b.h`
`c.cc, c.h`

and each of those `.cc` files look like this:

**outter.cc**:

```
#include "b.h"
// do something
```

**b.cc**

```
#include "c.h"
// do something
```

**c.cc**

```
//do something
```

In `outer.cc` is a bunch of API definitions. I want to generate a .so file so that other people can use my API when they link their programs against this .so file.

My questions include:

1. How to generate this .so file? I am basically "packing" all the code to a .so file
2. If I managed to generate this .so file, how to use it? Say I have a `main.cc` file in another directory `/home/xavier/test/` and I also have the generated .so file in `/home/xavier/test/`. How should I write this `main.cc` and how should I compile this main.cc file to make it use my API defined in outter.cc?

I am using Mac OS X and g++

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A makefile like follow:

```
all:a.so

a.so: outer.o b.o c.o
    g++ $^  -fPIC -shared -o $@
%.o:%.cc
    g++ $< -I(your header file path) -c -o $@
```

Don't forget the -c flag when generating .o files

if the liba.so in same folder with main.cc you can

```
g++ main.cc -la -o main
```

the main.cc should include outter.h b.h c.h

or you rename a.so to liba.so then put it into /usr/lib/
and run `g++ main.cc -la -o main`

Comment: And if the `outer.h` API is designed to hide the internals and types of `b.h` and `c.h`, then main.cc will only need to `#include <outer.h>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One more question! What if `b.h, c.h` and `outter.h` have different directory? What should I do with the `-I(your header file path)`?

Comment: @ConradParker Thank you for your comments. Yes `outter.h` is supposed to hide details of `b.h` and `c.h` to the API users. But can you be more specific on "designed to hide the internals and types"? An example would be great.

Comment: I just tried you method. It doesn't work from my side. 1. it should be `g++ $< -I(your header file path) -c -o $@`, you missed -c flag.  2. when I compiled main.cc `g++ main.cc -la -o main`, such error popped up: `fatal error: 'outter.h' file not found`. Do I need to put `outter.h, b.h, c.h` in `/home/xavier/test` as well?

Comment: i`m sorry, i miss -c,  and fatal error: 'outter.h' file not found,   you can g++ main.cc -I(your header file path) -la -o main

Comment: @Ace Thank you. Another question. Your method actually worked (if -c is added and header path is specified). However, when I run a test program (`./main.cc`) it says `dyld: Library not loaded: a.so; Referenced from: /some/path/./main; Reason: image not found; Abort trap: 6` Does this error runs a bell? `outter.cc` actually contains some Google protocol buffers API calls

Comment: The Google protocol buffers API, maybe you should -l   the buffers API library , you can check your binary with ldd command (I don`t know whether it exist in  MAC OS),  and you can see which library not loaded. And for the Google buffer API , I don`t know how to use it, you can search Google.